# JavaScript math to position a Div in the center (algorithm)

Tags: javascript, math, mobile, responsive-design

I am trying to position a div box which has a certain height and certain width to the center of a screen which has a certain height and a certain width.

The width and heights are detected JavaScript. I am trying to become a better programmer and math and programming not always my best traits. I realize I need to do some division and percent fix but need a pointer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var w=document.width;
var h=document.height;

var img_w=200;
var img_h=300;

var css=;

/*

Example

w=600;
h=400;

img_w=200;
img h=300;


therefore css will be

position:absolute;
top:150px;
left:100px;
right:100px;
bottom:100px;

see my image.

*/

document.writeln(css);
</script>
```

[image]

So basically, whatever the `img_w` and `img_h` are, the box should position with margin in the center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me suggest an alternative approach.

CSS is not a procedural but declarative language. Let the browser do the math for you and use `margin: auto`. I understand this is not what you are looking for, but CSS is just about it.

See http://jsfiddle.net/th43T/ for an example.

Answer (score 3):

The formula you are looking for is the following :

```
left = ( width - img_width ) / 2
top = ( height - img_height ) / 2
```

PS: In your example, you inverted `h` and `w`.

Answer (score 0):

I first thought the math is (as others pointed out)

The math is: (total width - image width) / 2. Same goes for height

But, why is top 150px and bottom 100px in your example?

Comment: The actual image proportions will change, therefore my image there above is centered.

Answer (score 0):

```
Block css:{
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
}

JS (useing jQuery): {
    block.css({
        'margin-left': '-' + (block.outerWidth() / 2), // margin-left: -1/2 of block width
        'margin-top': '-' + (block.outerHeight() / 2), // margin-top: -1/2 of block height
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep it centered during window resizing you will also have to check for the window resize event.

I created this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ekRff/1/

javascript:

```
function updateBoxPosition($box) {
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var left_pos = (window_width - $box.width()) / 2;
    var top_pos = (window_height - $box.height()) / 2;

    $box.css('left', left_pos);
    $box.css('top', top_pos);
}

$(function() {
    var $box = $("#box");
    var window_width = 0;
    var window_height = 0;

    var resizeTimer;
    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            updateBoxPosition($box);
        }, 25);
    });

    updateBoxPosition($box);          
});​
```

The top function handles the positioning and the binding for positioning is done during the onload event. It dose require jQuery but I do recommend it for this situation since there is a lot that differs between how browsers handle the width of a window.

The timer added for the resize event is for performance, the resize event gets fired rather frequently during a resize.